# amazon s3 - image downloading instead of displaying in browser

Tags: php, amazon-s3

This is driving me mad. I am uploading images to S3 using the php SDK. Whenever I browse to the image URL, the browser downloads the image opposed to displaying it.

I think its something to do with content type.

```
        // Prepare to upload the file to S3 bucket.
        $s3->create_object($bucket, $file_name, array(
                'contentType' => 'binary/octet-stream',
                'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
        ));
```

Can you help?

thanks

Comment: Could you post a sample of the image URL?

Comment: Perhaps try changing the content type to 'image/jpg' (assuming jpg of course)? http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
            $s3->create_object($bucket, $file_name, array(
                    'fileUpload' => $resized_image,
                    'contentType' => $_FILES['image']['type'],
                    'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
            ));
```

Comment: Those using AWS SDK for PHP 3.x with putObject() the case is different for the keys.  It will be 'ContentType' and 'ACL'.

Answer (score 20):

Your content type is wrong indeed.  It needs to be image/jpeg for JPGs, for instance.  See this site for a list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: $s3->create_object($bucket, $file_name, array(
                        'fileUpload' => $resized_image,
                        'contentType' => $_FILES['image']['type'],
                        'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
                ));

Answer (score 5):

**If you are working URL images use**

```
'ContentType'  => mime_content_type($absolutePathToImage),
```

instead of

```
$_FILES['image']['type']
```

Answer (score 3):

Working on your own, seemingly valid, assumption that it is the content type:

You need to set the correct content type for the image being upload, the following list contains all the most common types

```
* image/gif: GIF image
* image/jpeg: JPEG JFIF image
* image/png: Portable Network Graphics
* image/svg+xml: SVG vector image
* image/tiff: Tag Image File Format
* image/vnd.microsoft.icon: ICO image
```

So a rework of your sample code for a png upload:

```
// Prepare to upload the file to S3 bucket.
$s3->create_object($bucket, $file_name, array(
            'contentType' => 'image/png',
            'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
));
```

Comment: changed the content type to image/jpg and still getting the download dialogue

Comment: Could you post a sample of the image url?

Comment: RESOLVED. Need to add the fileUpload key.