# Amazon s3 viewing the uploaded image will let me download the image

Tags: php, javascript, amazon-s3

I'm uploading an image in Amazon s3 but when I try to view the file in the browser it lets me download the image, how would I disable that one? My expected outcome should be seeing the image in the browser. How would I do that one?

I heard something of setting the header but I'm not familiar with that on.

Can someone teach me how to accomplish this one.

Thanks!

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated and rewarded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [amazon s3 - image downloading instead of displaying in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751360/amazon-s3-image-downloading-instead-of-displaying-in-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)?

You need to set the correct `Content-Type` for your image, otherwise the default is `application/octet-stream` which is why your browser downloads the file. There's a good listing of values on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

```
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$response = $s3->create_object('my-bucket', 'myimgae.jpg', array(
    'contentType' => 'image/jpeg'
));

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
```

Or for existing objects in S3, you can use [`change_content_type`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/change_content_type)

Finally, if you are [generating pre-signed urls](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_url), you can dynamically set the `content-type`.

```
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

// Get the URL
$url = $s3->get_object_url('bucket', 'myimage.jpg', '5 minutes', array(
    'response' => array(
        'content-type' => 'image/jpeg'
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Yes I am using AWS SDK for PHP.
I already tested it using the 'content-type' => 'image/jpeg'.
My system also allows png and gif, so how would I make the 'content-type' flexible whering if the file extension is gif then I would make it image/gif or if png i would make it image/png.
Thanks!

Comment: @ElsonSolano - I don't know of any way other than looking at the extension of the file and then looking up the appropriate `content-type`.

Comment: I figured it out. I just used $_FILES['type'].
That outputs the file type/extension of the uploaded file. example 'image/jpeg'. So we could type in 'content-type => $_FILES['type']
Anyway, thanks for answering! :)