# Audio URL get downloaded instead of playing in the browser - DigitalOcean Spaces/Buckets

Tags: html, url, amazon-s3, html5-audio, digital-ocean

I am using DigitalOcean Spaces/Buckets to store audio files and have a URL being generated which points to that file.
In my html file, I am accessing that audio as:

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="my_digital_ocean_file_url">
</audio>
```

This file is not getting played on the front-end and when I enter the URL on chrome, the file gets downloaded instead of playing on the browser. Is there a way to make the files on the URL playable?

Comment: Most probably you hit a CORS policy, check the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the backend. You need to provide 'contentType' as audio. The implementation is different based on the programming language you are using for the backend. Please check the sample code in PHP.

```
 $s3->create_object($bucket, $file_name, array(
                    'fileUpload' => $resized_image,
                    'contentType' => $_FILES['image']['type'],
                    'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
            ));
```

The above issue is not limited to audio files, it's for PDF, Images as well. Follow are some helpful reference

[How to view pdf's stored in spaces without them being downloaded](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-view-pdf-s-stored-in-spaces-without-them-being-downloaded)

[amazon s3 - image downloading instead of displaying in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751360/amazon-s3-image-downloading-instead-of-displaying-in-browser)

Comment: I did not need to do this. My Browser was outdated and the HTML5 audio did not support that version. I updated the browser and it works perfectly fine. But thank you for this solution as well. I will look into this as well and try to explore it more. Might come handy in future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using and outdated browser. Updating the browser solved the issues for me.